# How to add single values (shapes) to geom_split_violin() based on groups?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapes, violin-plot

I would like to add single reference values to each of my half violins.

[image]

It should look something like this with a shape:
[image]

Here is the code for my current plot (first img):

```
ggplot(data = csi, aes(x=species,y=CSI, fill=time))+
  geom_split_violin(stat = "ydensity", trim = T,scale = "width")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("grey40","grey60"))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=35,hjust = 1))
```

And this is how my dataset looks like:

```
str(csi)
'data.frame':   265196 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ species: Factor w/ 17 levels "Tilia europaea",..: 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 ...
 $ time   : Factor w/ 2 levels "present","future": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ CSI    : num  0.395 0.66 0.615 0.612 0.808 ...

head(csi)
           species    time       CSI
1 Acer platanoides present 0.3953996
2 Acer platanoides present 0.6603609
3 Acer platanoides present 0.6148618
...
```

I have an additional dataframe with the values per species and time I'd like to add to my plot:

```
                 species    time      mean
1       Acer platanoides present 0.7069132
2       Acer platanoides  future 0.4984167
3            Acer rubrum present 0.2257700
4            Acer rubrum  future 0.1622086
...
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance and best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer I was looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38590629/overlay-scatterpoints-on-split-violin-plot-with-ggplot2).
For `geom_point()` just the addition `position=position_dodge(width=0.7)` or another number is needed. Thanks to the people from the link above!

Here is my plot:
[image]

And the final code: (I merged the two df mentioned in the first post adding another col `"mean"` to the first df)

```
  geom_split_violin(aes(x = species,y = CSI, fill = time),
                    stat = "ydensity", trim = T, scale = "width")+
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = species, y = mean, shape = time), position = position_dodge(width = 0.7))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=35,hjust = 1))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks for taking the time and adding this answer. Please consider accepting your answer once you are able to do so, this may take a day or two. This way, the question won't mark as unanswered anymore. Cheers