# Why can´t I reproduce a simple grouped violin plot from a tutorial

Tags: r, violin-plot

I´d like to reproduce the simple grouped violin plot from the tutorial here:

http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-violin-plot-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization

It uses the built in ToothGrowth dataset so it should be easily reproducible.

I use this code (in a blank R script after restarting RScript Software)

```
# Change violin plot colors by groups
ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len, fill=supp)) +
  geom_violin()
```

And I get this result, totally different from the tutorial example.
My Result:
[image: My Result]

Tutorial Example = lower picture
[image: Tutorial example]

Everything else up to this point in the Tutorial was easily reproducible and a great help in learning :)
So what is my mistake? I want it to look like the example in the tutorial.

Interestingly I can easily reproduce the same kind of violin plot using the code provided as an example in this question

[Split violin plot with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717353/split-violin-plot-with-ggplot2)

My Specs:
Win7 64bit (German Version, Software all english) - 
RStudio newest Version 1.0.143 - 
R newest Version Version 3.40.7034.0 -

Comment: The tutorial example seems to have been produced with `ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=factor(dose), y=len, fill=supp)) +     geom_violin()`

Comment: Thanks, this works! Didn´t see the difference at first ;)  If you make it an answer I can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial example seems to have been produced with

```
ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=factor(dose), y=len, fill=supp)) + geom_violin()
```