# Split violin plot with ggplot2 with quantiles

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggproto

In order to plot half densities, I am using the function described in this post: [Split violin plot with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717353/split-violin-plot-with-ggplot2)

However, when I want to draw the quantiles on the densities, like on a normal `geom_violin()` or `geom_boxplot()`, I obtain an error message.

I would also be interested in adding the number of observations above each half density.

Here is an example of what I would like to obtain:

```
data("diamonds")
library(ggplot2)

# Function described in a previous post
GeomSplitViolin <- ggproto("GeomSplitViolin", GeomViolin, draw_group = function(self, data, ..., draw_quantiles = NULL){
  data <- transform(data, xminv = x - violinwidth * (x - xmin), xmaxv = x + violinwidth * (xmax - x))
  grp <- data[1,'group']
  newdata <- plyr::arrange(transform(data, x = if(grp%%2==1) xminv else xmaxv), if(grp%%2==1) y else -y)
  newdata <- rbind(newdata[1, ], newdata, newdata[nrow(newdata), ], newdata[1, ])
  newdata[c(1,nrow(newdata)-1,nrow(newdata)), 'x'] <- round(newdata[1, 'x']) 
  if (length(draw_quantiles) > 0 & !scales::zero_range(range(data$y))) {
    stopifnot(all(draw_quantiles >= 0), all(draw_quantiles <= 
                                              1))
    quantiles <- create_quantile_segment_frame(data, draw_quantiles)
    aesthetics <- data[rep(1, nrow(quantiles)), setdiff(names(data), c("x", "y")), drop = FALSE]
    aesthetics$alpha <- rep(1, nrow(quantiles))
    both <- cbind(quantiles, aesthetics)
    quantile_grob <- GeomPath$draw_panel(both, ...)
    ggplot2:::ggname("geom_split_violin", grobTree(GeomPolygon$draw_panel(newdata, ...), quantile_grob))
  }
  else {
    ggplot2:::ggname("geom_split_violin", GeomPolygon$draw_panel(newdata, ...))
  }
})

geom_split_violin <- function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "ydensity", position = "identity", ..., draw_quantiles = NULL, trim = TRUE, scale = "area", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE) {
  layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomSplitViolin, position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes, params = list(trim = trim, scale = scale, draw_quantiles = draw_quantiles, na.rm = na.rm, ...))
}

tmp <- diamonds[which(diamonds$cut %in% c("Fair", "Good")), ]

# Obtained plot
ggplot(tmp, aes(as.factor(color), carat, fill = cut)) +
  geom_split_violin()

# Error due to internal functions (interleave, ...)
ggplot(tmp, aes(as.factor(color), carat, fill = cut)) +
  geom_split_violin(draw_quantiles = 0.5)

# Function to return number of observation
give_n = function(x, y_up = y_upper) {
  data.frame(y = y_up * 1.06,
             label = paste("n =", length(x))
  )
}

# Code to add number of observations above each half density
new_plot = given_plot +
  # Give back only length of data
  stat_summary(fun.data = give_n, aes(x = as.factor(variable)), geom = "text")
```

Comment: The errors can be solved by using `ggplot2:::create_quantile_segment_frame` and `grid::grobTree` in `GeomSplitViolin`, although the result might not be satisfactory.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We can make further adjustments to the function by @YAK, and add some adjustments to `create_quantile_segment_frame`:

```
GeomSplitViolin <- ggproto("GeomSplitViolin", GeomViolin,
  draw_group = function(self, data, ..., draw_quantiles = NULL) {
    # Original function by Jan Gleixner (@jan-glx)
    # Adjustments by Wouter van der Bijl (@Axeman)
    data <- transform(data, xminv = x - violinwidth * (x - xmin), xmaxv = x + violinwidth * (xmax - x))
    grp <- data[1, "group"]
    newdata <- plyr::arrange(transform(data, x = if (grp %% 2 == 1) xminv else xmaxv), if (grp %% 2 == 1) y else -y)
    newdata <- rbind(newdata[1, ], newdata, newdata[nrow(newdata), ], newdata[1, ])
    newdata[c(1, nrow(newdata) - 1, nrow(newdata)), "x"] <- round(newdata[1, "x"])
    if (length(draw_quantiles) > 0 & !scales::zero_range(range(data$y))) {
      stopifnot(all(draw_quantiles >= 0), all(draw_quantiles <= 1))
      quantiles <- create_quantile_segment_frame(data, draw_quantiles, split = TRUE, grp = grp)
      aesthetics <- data[rep(1, nrow(quantiles)), setdiff(names(data), c("x", "y")), drop = FALSE]
      aesthetics$alpha <- rep(1, nrow(quantiles))
      both <- cbind(quantiles, aesthetics)
      quantile_grob <- GeomPath$draw_panel(both, ...)
      ggplot2:::ggname("geom_split_violin", grid::grobTree(GeomPolygon$draw_panel(newdata, ...), quantile_grob))
    }
    else {
      ggplot2:::ggname("geom_split_violin", GeomPolygon$draw_panel(newdata, ...))
    }
  }
)

create_quantile_segment_frame <- function(data, draw_quantiles, split = FALSE, grp = NULL) {
  dens <- cumsum(data$density) / sum(data$density)
  ecdf <- stats::approxfun(dens, data$y)
  ys <- ecdf(draw_quantiles)
  violin.xminvs <- (stats::approxfun(data$y, data$xminv))(ys)
  violin.xmaxvs <- (stats::approxfun(data$y, data$xmaxv))(ys)
  violin.xs <- (stats::approxfun(data$y, data$x))(ys)
  if (grp %% 2 == 0) {
    data.frame(
      x = ggplot2:::interleave(violin.xs, violin.xmaxvs),
      y = rep(ys, each = 2), group = rep(ys, each = 2)
    )
  } else {
    data.frame(
      x = ggplot2:::interleave(violin.xminvs, violin.xs),
      y = rep(ys, each = 2), group = rep(ys, each = 2)
    )
  }
}

geom_split_violin <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "ydensity", position = "identity", ..., 
                              draw_quantiles = NULL, trim = TRUE, scale = "area", na.rm = FALSE, 
                              show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE) {
  layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomSplitViolin, position = position, 
        show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes, 
        params = list(trim = trim, scale = scale, draw_quantiles = draw_quantiles, na.rm = na.rm, ...))
}
```

Then simply plot:

```
ggplot(diamonds[which(diamonds$cut %in% c("Fair", "Good")), ],
       aes(as.factor(color), carat, fill = cut)) +
  geom_split_violin(draw_quantiles = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75))
```

[image]

Comment: How does one add facets to the above figure? Say, I want to facet by clarity? Tried adding facet_wrap  ggplot(tmp, aes(as.factor(color), carat, fill = cut)) + geom_split_violin(draw_quantiles = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)) + facet_wrap(.~clarity)

Comment: Can we extend to a nested case, as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49120060/ggplot2-display-blocks-of-nested-split-violins.

Comment: Thanks! this is better than the introdataviz package which has a bug with the draw_quntiles.