# Add boxplot and stats to split violin plot in ggplot2 (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, split, boxplot, violin-plot

I love the split violin plot and @jan-glx 's awesome `geom_split_violin` function created here: [Split violin plot with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717353/split-violin-plot-with-ggplot2).

I would love to add split boxplots and stats to this, as I explain below.

First, to be complete, here are the full data and code.

**Data** (copied from above link)

```
 set.seed(20160229)
 my_data = data.frame(
     y=c(rnorm(1000), rnorm(1000, 0.5), rnorm(1000, 1), rnorm(1000, 1.5)),
     x=c(rep('a', 2000), rep('b', 2000)),
     m=c(rep('i', 1000), rep('j', 2000), rep('i', 1000)))
```

**Code to create** `geom_split_violin` **function** (copied from above link)

```
 library('ggplot2')
 GeomSplitViolin <- ggproto("GeomSplitViolin", GeomViolin, 
                       draw_group = function(self, data, ..., draw_quantiles = NULL) {
    data <- transform(data, xminv = x - violinwidth * (x - xmin), xmaxv = x + violinwidth * (xmax - x))
   grp <- data[1, "group"]
   newdata <- plyr::arrange(transform(data, x = if (grp %% 2 == 1) xminv else xmaxv), if (grp %% 2 == 1) y else -y)
   newdata <- rbind(newdata[1, ], newdata, newdata[nrow(newdata), ], newdata[1, ])
   newdata[c(1, nrow(newdata) - 1, nrow(newdata)), "x"] <- round(newdata[1, "x"])
   if (length(draw_quantiles) > 0 & !scales::zero_range(range(data$y))) {
     stopifnot(all(draw_quantiles >= 0), all(draw_quantiles <=
       1))
     quantiles <- ggplot2:::create_quantile_segment_frame(data, draw_quantiles)
     aesthetics <- data[rep(1, nrow(quantiles)), setdiff(names(data), c("x", "y")), drop = FALSE]
     aesthetics$alpha <- rep(1, nrow(quantiles))
     both <- cbind(quantiles, aesthetics)
     quantile_grob <- GeomPath$draw_panel(both, ...)
     ggplot2:::ggname("geom_split_violin", grid::grobTree(GeomPolygon$draw_panel(newdata, ...), quantile_grob))
   }
   else {
     ggplot2:::ggname("geom_split_violin", GeomPolygon$draw_panel(newdata, ...))
   }
 })
 geom_split_violin <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "ydensity", position = "identity", ..., 
                               draw_quantiles = NULL, trim = TRUE, scale = "area", na.rm = FALSE, 
                               show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE) {
   layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomSplitViolin, 
         position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes, 
         params = list(trim = trim, scale = scale, draw_quantiles = draw_quantiles, na.rm = na.rm, ...))
 }
```

**My attempt to add boxplots and stats**

Here is the code that I used to try to add:

1. Split boxplots.
2. P values using `wilcox.test` stats.
3. Sample sizes (n).

Code:

```
 library(ggpubr)
 give.n <- function(x){return(y = -2.6, label = length(x))}
 ggplot(my_data, aes(x, y, fill = m)) + 
      geom_split_violin() + 
      geom_boxplot(width = 0.2, notch = TRUE, fill="white", outlier.shape = NA) + 
      stat_summary(fun.data = give.n, geom = "text") + 
      stat_compare_means(aes(label = ifelse(p < 1.e-4, sprintf("p = %2.1e", 
           as.numeric(..p.format..)), sprintf("p = %5.4f", 
           as.numeric(..p.format..)))), method = "wilcox.test", paired = FALSE) + 
      stat_summary(fun.data = give.n, geom = "text")
```

This is the result:
[image]
Unfortunately, this throws an error and is not quite where I hoped to get, because it is missing the p values and the sample sizes (n) and the boxplots are not split. I also tried one of @Axeman 's excellent suggestions in another SO answer, but no luck so far.

What I am hoping to achieve is something similar to this (also with p values no longer "NA"):
[image]
This seems a big challenge, but I am hoping someone out there might be able to help, as others will probably love this as much as me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this topic might've solved it (using the same source code you did):
[ggplot split violin plot with horizontal mean lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51228076/ggplot-split-violin-plot-with-horizontal-mean-lines)

Here's some example data:

```
set.seed(20160229)

my_data = data.frame(
  y=c(rnorm(1000), rnorm(1000, 0.5), rnorm(1000, 1), rnorm(1000, 
1.5)),
  x=c(rep('a', 2000), rep('b', 2000)),
  m=c(rep('i', 1000), rep('j', 2000), rep('i', 1000))
)
```

Here's the extension for geom_violin to create split_geom_violin:

```
GeomSplitViolin <- ggproto("GeomSplitViolin", GeomViolin, draw_group = function(self, data, ..., draw_quantiles = NULL){
  data <- transform(data, xminv = x - violinwidth * (x - xmin), xmaxv = x + violinwidth * (xmax - x))
  grp <- data[1,'group']
  newdata <- plyr::arrange(transform(data, x = if(grp%%2==1) xminv else xmaxv), if(grp%%2==1) y else -y)
  newdata <- rbind(newdata[1, ], newdata, newdata[nrow(newdata), ], newdata[1, ])
  newdata[c(1,nrow(newdata)-1,nrow(newdata)), 'x'] <- round(newdata[1, 'x']) 
  if (length(draw_quantiles) > 0 & !scales::zero_range(range(data$y))) {
    stopifnot(all(draw_quantiles >= 0), all(draw_quantiles <= 
                                              1))
    quantiles <- ggplot2:::create_quantile_segment_frame(data, draw_quantiles)
    aesthetics <- data[rep(1, nrow(quantiles)), setdiff(names(data), c("x", "y")), drop = FALSE]
    aesthetics$alpha <- rep(1, nrow(quantiles))
    both <- cbind(quantiles, aesthetics)
    quantile_grob <- GeomPath$draw_panel(both, ...)
    ggplot2:::ggname("geom_split_violin", grid::grobTree(GeomPolygon$draw_panel(newdata, ...), quantile_grob))
  }
  else {
    ggplot2:::ggname("geom_split_violin", GeomPolygon$draw_panel(newdata, ...))
  }
})

geom_split_violin <- function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "ydensity", position = "identity", ..., draw_quantiles = NULL, trim = TRUE, scale = "area", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE) {
  layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomSplitViolin, position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes, params = list(trim = trim, scale = scale, draw_quantiles = draw_quantiles, na.rm = na.rm, ...))
}
```

Here's the code for the graph:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(my_data, aes(x, y, fill=m)) + 
  geom_split_violin(trim = TRUE) + 
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.25, notch = FALSE, notchwidth = .4, outlier.shape = NA, coef=0) +
  labs(x=NULL,y="GM Attitude Score") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 20)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("0" = "Control\nCondition", "1" = "GM\nCondition")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#E69F00", "#999999"), 
                    name="Survey\nPart",
                    breaks=c("1", "2"),
                    labels=c("Time 1", "Time 5"))
```

[Produced graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9NJM.png)

Comment: Very nice! Thank you :)