# manual specification of draw_quantile argument in violin plot call in R

Tags: r, draw, quantile, violin-plot

Using the `iris` data:

```
require(ggplot2)
    ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
    geom_violin(draw_quantiles = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75))
```

We get:
[image]

How can I keep the straight line for the means but use dashed lines instead for the other two quantiles ?

I have used the very handy function of @jan-glx for my own data here: [Split violin plot with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717353/split-violin-plot-with-ggplot2) , but I honestly don't understand everything in this code. Plus it seems to be automatic in python according to this link https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html , but I only work with R.

And if I compute this :

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_violin(draw_quantiles = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75),
              linetype = "dashed")
```

I get all the lines in `dashed` type :
[image]

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem as you. This is probably not the most elegant way to do so, but I first plotted the dashed line and then replotted the violin with `fill="transparent"`.

You can control which quartiles to plot in the vector designated for `draw_quantiles` in `geom_violin()`. First draw the 25 and 75% quartiles with dashed lines than replot the violin with only the 50% quartile and solid line. Please note that the 50% quartile represents the median, not the mean value.

Here is the code:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
geom_violin(draw_quantiles = c(0.25, 0.75),
      linetype = "dashed") +
geom_violin(fill="transparent",draw_quantiles = 0.5)
```

To get the actual mean, you must use the `stat_summary()`, but instead of a line, you get a point.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
geom_violin(draw_quantiles = c(0.25, 0.75),
  linetype = "dashed") +
geom_violin(fill="transparent",draw_quantiles = 0.5) +
stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=20, size=7, color="red", fill="red")
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work for me : I get an error message saying ']' unexpected in:
"                linetype = "dashed") +
    geom_violin(fill="transparent")]"

If I remove the square brackets I get almost what I want except for the quantiles (still in dashed)