# Not to draw specific part of polygon

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data structure:

```
y <- rep(1:10, 2)
group <- rep(c('a', 'b'), each = 10)
dens <- c(c(seq(from = 0, to = 0.8, by = 0.1), 0),
           c(seq(from = -0, to = -0.8, by = -0.1), 0))
my_dat <- data.frame(group, dens, y, stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
```

These are calculated density disributions, in order to make a grouped violin plot, such as in
[Split violin plot with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717353/split-violin-plot-with-ggplot2?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

```
# Plot 1:
  require(ggplot2)
  ggplot(my_dat, aes(x = dens, y = y, fill = group)) +
  geom_polygon(color = 'black', show.legend = FALSE)
```

Now this is simplified, because my data contains hundreds of rows for a smooth outline. (However, there is the central vertical line in *my case*.) I would now like to remove exactly this vertical central line.
(I guess the problem is removing *any* specified part of the polygon.)

An idea in my example was to overplot this with a vertical line:

```
#Plot 2
  ggplot(my_dat, aes(x = dens, y = y, fill = group)) +
  geom_polygon(color = 'black', show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_segment(x = 0, 
               xend = 0, 
               y = min(y) + 0.2, 
               yend = max(y) - 0.2, 
               color = '#00BFC4')
```

[image]

But to get the end of the over plotting segment line correct is tricky. (I have purposefully left the line a bit too short for demonstration)

**edit**

the groups are **not** distributed in a symmetrical fashion, although my example strongly suggests so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always just plot another polygon on top

```
x <- with(my_dat, chull(dens, y))
my_dat2 <- my_dat[c(x, x[1L]), ]

ggplot(my_dat, aes(x = dens, y = y, fill = group)) +
  geom_polygon(show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_polygon(data = my_dat2, aes(group = 1), size = 1,
               fill = 'transparent',
               # fill = NA,  ## or this
               color = 'black')
```

[image]

Comment: not really. This works only for symmetric groups. The whole point of separating the two groups is that they are *not* symmetrical. Should have specified this better. Will add this to the question

Comment: that seems irrelevant to me, can you amend your example

Comment: OK you were right! Sorry! It is indeed irrelevant. Oops, I obviously have not immediately understood your code (did not know `chull`, and I have to get my head around your use of `with`...). Cool. many thanks.

Comment: great! but I think this solution may not work if there are concave points along your perimeter in which case the convex hull would not lay on the perimeter

Comment: Sorry to come back to you again. I was on a run and have not checked it on my real data. It doesn't work with it. I guess I have to make another example, because it does not work with more complex polygons because (I assume) `chull` only creates certain 'edge points'.... Can't do this today, will do tomorrow. Nevertheless, I leave the answer accepted because it answers my specific question

Answer (score 1):

I think the simpler solution is to first draw all the outlines and then all the filled areas. This should work for any arbitrary polygon shapes.

```
y <- rep(1:10, 2)
group <- rep(c('a', 'b'), each = 10)
dens <- c(c(seq(from = 0, to = 0.8, by = 0.1), 0),
         c(seq(from = -0, to = -0.8, by = -0.1), 0))
my_dat <- data.frame(group, dens, y, stringsAsFactors = FALSE )

require(ggplot2)
ggplot(my_dat, aes(x = dens, y = y)) +
  geom_polygon(color = 'black', fill = NA, size = 2) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = group), color = NA)
```

[image]

Comment: that's a very neat twist to swap the group mapping into the respective geom calls. Now, you couldn't know that, because I hadn't put this into the question (because I hadn't realised that this would be of importance in this moment)...  but I am using alpha for my fill, so the underlying plot still 'shines through'...