# Geom_violinhalf Plotting Side

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot half of a violin plot using `geom_violinhalf` from the package `see`. I have been able to plot the right half of the violin plot, but I cannot figure out how to plot just the *left* side of the violin. Here is an example:

```
install.packages('see')
install.packages('tidyverse')
library(see)
library(tidyverse)

df1 = as.data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 10000, ncol = 3))
colnames(df1) = c('d','y','x')
df1[,2] = rnorm(10000,10,5)
df1[,1] = sample(seq(-5,70,.1),10000, replace=TRUE)
df1$x <- floor(df1$d /5) * 5

ggplot(df1, aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_violinhalf(data=df1, aes(group = x), 
                  scale = 'width', fill = alpha('red', 0.2), 
                  color = alpha('red',0.2)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = d), size = 1.2, col = alpha('grey', 0.2)) +
  theme_classic()
```

Ideally the package would just allow a simple argument i.e. `side = 'left'`  to just plot the violin plot on the left side, but I can't find such an argument within the function. If there's a different package or command I could use instead, I'd be interested in that, but I've had issues with `vioplot()` so I'd rather not use that.

Also, I have been trying to get the code from

```
 Plot only one side/half of the violin plot
```

to work but it has not been working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update - the code in the answer from @PoGibas within [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52034747/plot-only-one-side-half-of-the-violin-plot) works perfectly as long as `mapping = aes = group(x)`. This code produces the exact same result as `geom_violinhalf`, but just on the left side of the violin as opposed to the right.