# aes() and aes_string() produce different behaviors in split_violin_plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

I am trying to use a function from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717353/split-violin-plot-with-ggplot2) to produce a split violin plot.

Here's the code:

```
GeomSplitViolin <- ggproto("GeomSplitViolin", GeomViolin, draw_group = function(self, data, ..., draw_quantiles = NULL){
  data <- transform(data, xminv = x - violinwidth * (x - xmin), xmaxv = x + violinwidth * (xmax - x))
  grp <- data[1,'group']
  newdata <- plyr::arrange(transform(data, x = if(grp%%2==1) xminv else xmaxv), if(grp%%2==1) y else -y)
  newdata <- rbind(newdata[1, ], newdata, newdata[nrow(newdata), ], newdata[1, ])
  newdata[c(1,nrow(newdata)-1,nrow(newdata)), 'x'] <- round(newdata[1, 'x']) 
  if (length(draw_quantiles) > 0 & !scales::zero_range(range(data$y))) {
    stopifnot(all(draw_quantiles >= 0), all(draw_quantiles <= 
                                              1))
    quantiles <- ggplot2:::create_quantile_segment_frame(data, draw_quantiles)
    aesthetics <- data[rep(1, nrow(quantiles)), setdiff(names(data), c("x", "y")), drop = FALSE]
    aesthetics$alpha <- rep(1, nrow(quantiles))
    both <- cbind(quantiles, aesthetics)
    quantile_grob <- GeomPath$draw_panel(both, ...)
    ggplot2:::ggname("geom_split_violin", grid::grobTree(GeomPolygon$draw_panel(newdata, ...), quantile_grob))
  }
  else {
    ggplot2:::ggname("geom_split_violin", GeomPolygon$draw_panel(newdata, ...))
  }
})

geom_split_violin <- function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "ydensity", position = "identity", ..., draw_quantiles = NULL, trim = TRUE, scale = "area", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE) {
  layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomSplitViolin, position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes, params = list(trim = trim, scale = scale, draw_quantiles = draw_quantiles, na.rm = na.rm, ...))
}
```

Here's an example dataset:

```
set.seed(20160229)
my_data = data.frame(
  y=c(rnorm(1000), rnorm(1000, 0.5), rnorm(1000, 1), rnorm(1000, 1.5)),
  x=c(rep('a', 2000), rep('b', 2000)),
  m=c(rep('i', 1000), rep('j', 2000), rep('i', 1000))
)
```

Use `aes()` in the plot function, we could get the normal plot

```
ggplot(my_data, aes(x, y, fill=m)) + geom_split_violin()
```

[image]

But if use `aes_string()`, I got a weird plot where two split violin on top of each other.

```
ggplot(my_data, aes_string(x='x', y='y', fill='m')) + geom_split_violin()
```

[image]

I do not have a good understanding of how `aes` vs. `aes_string` might lead to this difference. Hope someone could give me a hint. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looks like the problem is the `grp%%2==1` check. You seem to be assuming that the groups are going to be in some order? The `aes()` and `aes_string()` versions do seem to return the groups in a different order of some reason, but plotting shouldn't depend on that ordering. How do you want to decide which one is supposed to go on the left and which is supposed to go on the right?

Comment: I don't have specific preference which one go to the left and right. But in this case, seems like both went to the left. Do you know how was that controlled?

Comment: There is an open issue on the github repo about this. See [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2896)

Comment: Wow, that's exactly same question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `aes_string()`, you can use [tidy evaluation](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2018/07/ggplot2-3-0-0/) approach in `ggplot2 3.0` or higher by:

- converting the input strings to variables using `sym()`
- unquote them inside `aes()` using `!!` so they get evaluated

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(my_data, aes(x = !!sym('x'), y = !!sym('y'), fill = !!sym('m'))) + geom_split_violin()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-10-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this works! Still trying to understand under the hood why they produce different behaviors.

Comment: I recommend not using `aes_string` as it was deprecated when tidy evaluation was made possible in ggplot2. I don't think they will spend that much time improving it anymore