# Error with labels in split violin plot in ggplot2 (R) due to missing values

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, tidyverse, violin-plot

I am generating split violin plots using the `geom_split_violin` function created here: [Split violin plot with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717353/split-violin-plot-with-ggplot2).

Then, I add labels for sample sizes (n = ...) for each split violin. However, there are some missing values, which results in mislabelling from the missing data onward.

Using the code below, this is the result:
[image]

In the bottom grid (B), under p2, there are no values for fill `value = 1`. This results in mislabelling of the split violins thereafter. Specifically, the labels `n = 3` and `n = 108` are swapped.

Might there be a way to solve this?

Here is the full code:

```
 # Create data
 set.seed(12345)
 my_data = data.frame(
     y=c(rnorm(1000, 15)),
     type=c(rep("A", 635), rep("B", 365)),
     variable=c(rep("p1", 151), rep("p2", 287), rep("p3", 197), 
             rep("p1", 73), rep("p2", 181), rep("p3", 111)),
     value=c(rep("0", 89), rep("1", 62), 
            rep("0", 151), rep("1", 136), 
            rep("0", 101), rep("1", 96), 
            rep("0", 39), rep("1", 34), 
            rep("0", 181), 
            rep("0", 108), rep("1", 3)))
 # Code to create geom_split_violin function from link above
 library('ggplot2')
 GeomSplitViolin <- ggproto("GeomSplitViolin", GeomViolin, 
                       draw_group = function(self, data, ..., draw_quantiles = NULL) {
    data <- transform(data, xminv = x - violinwidth * (x - xmin), xmaxv = x + violinwidth * (xmax - x))
   grp <- data[1, "group"]
   newdata <- plyr::arrange(transform(data, x = if (grp %% 2 == 1) xminv else xmaxv), if (grp %% 2 == 1) y else -y)
   newdata <- rbind(newdata[1, ], newdata, newdata[nrow(newdata), ], newdata[1, ])
   newdata[c(1, nrow(newdata) - 1, nrow(newdata)), "x"] <- round(newdata[1, "x"])
   if (length(draw_quantiles) > 0 & !scales::zero_range(range(data$y))) {
     stopifnot(all(draw_quantiles >= 0), all(draw_quantiles <=
       1))
     quantiles <- ggplot2:::create_quantile_segment_frame(data, draw_quantiles)
     aesthetics <- data[rep(1, nrow(quantiles)), setdiff(names(data), c("x", "y")), drop = FALSE]
     aesthetics$alpha <- rep(1, nrow(quantiles))
     both <- cbind(quantiles, aesthetics)
     quantile_grob <- GeomPath$draw_panel(both, ...)
     ggplot2:::ggname("geom_split_violin", grid::grobTree(GeomPolygon$draw_panel(newdata, ...), quantile_grob))
   }
   else {
     ggplot2:::ggname("geom_split_violin", GeomPolygon$draw_panel(newdata, ...))
   }
 })
 geom_split_violin <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "ydensity", position = "identity", ..., 
                               draw_quantiles = NULL, trim = TRUE, scale = "area", na.rm = FALSE, 
                               show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE) {
   layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomSplitViolin, 
         position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes, 
         params = list(trim = trim, scale = scale, draw_quantiles = draw_quantiles, na.rm = na.rm, ...))
 }
 # Add labels 'n = ...'
 give_n = function(x, y_lo = 12) {
      data.frame(y = y_lo,
              label = paste("n =", length(x)))
 }
 # Plot data
 ggplot(my_data, aes(variable, y, fill = value)) + 
      geom_split_violin() + 
      facet_grid(type ~ ., scales = "free_y") + 
      stat_summary(fun.data = give_n, aes(x = as.factor(variable)), 
      geom = "text", position = position_nudge(x = c(-0.25, 0.25)))
```

Comment: for b/p2 you have a length 1 label but a length 2 nudge (`x = c(-0.25, 0.25)`), so it throws off the rest. You can try `position_dodge(width = 1)` instead

Comment: Woohoooo! Fantastic! Thank you so much! If you want to put this as an answer, I'll tick and up-vote it.