# Solid color legend for split violin plot (ggplot)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, violin-plot

I'm trying to get the legend colors in this split violin plot to be solid. I've successfully removed the lines that were here (following a different post on this site), but I can't figure out how to proceed.

[image: split violins]

```
ctn_sv <- ggplot(z, aes(x = time, y = ctn_mean, fill = group), position = position_dodge(.9), alpha = .01) + 
  geom_split_violin(trim = TRUE, alpha = 0.65) +
  ggtitle("CTN: FFF vs ZZZ")+
  theme_bw() + theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, fun.min = mean, fun.max = mean,
               geom = "crossbar", 
               width = 0.25,
               position = position_dodge(width = .25)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = 0)),
         color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = 0)))
```

I used the code for split violin plot from here [Split violin plot with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717353/split-violin-plot-with-ggplot2)

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: How did you draw the mean line for each splitted violon? I get only a general mean line, I guess for each entire group in the x-axis but not by `fill` grouping...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your geom="crossbar" is giving you that issue. You can use show.legend=FALSE in stat_summary to resolve this. See below code and corresponding output:

```
set.seed(20160229)

z = data.frame(
  y=c(rnorm(1000), rnorm(1000, 0.5), rnorm(1000, 1), rnorm(1000, 1.5)),
  x=c(rep('a', 2000), rep('b', 2000)),
  group=c(rep('i', 1000), rep('j', 2000), rep('i', 1000))
)

ctn_sv <- ggplot(z, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = group), position = position_dodge(.9), alpha = .71) + 
  geom_split_violin(trim = TRUE, alpha = 0.65) +
  ggtitle("CTN: FFF vs ZZZ")+
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, fun.min = mean, fun.max = mean,
               geom = "crossbar", 
               width = 0.25,
               show.legend = FALSE,
               position = position_dodge(width = .25)) 
ctn_sv
```

[image: output]