# Modify `geom_violin` to plot a histogram instead of a density?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Would it be possible to extend `geom_violon` (and ideally `geom_split_violin` as in  [@jan-glx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870254/jan-glx)'s answer here [Split violin plot with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717353/split-violin-plot-with-ggplot2#))?

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Hi! I (and many others here) would be happy to _help_ you do this. What part are you stuck at?

Comment: @AllanCameron I realized that one can do two-sided geom_dotplot with just the existing function but plotting twice with 2 different `stackdir`, but geom_dotplot really only works with few data points. What I really want is a histogram version of `geom_violin` and `geom_split_violin`. Any suggestions here?

Comment: Would you be content with a rectangular kernel? Like `ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + geom_violin(kernel = "rectangular")`?