# Two Y-Axes for Violin Plots? - R

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I am trying to visualize my data of biomass for various size classes at different sampling depths - depths are used multiple times for each size class.

I would like to use a violin plot or something similar, as I think it would be good to show the average Biomass at varying depths. However, I am unsure if that is possible with two continuous variables (depth, biomass).

Is there a possible way to visualize this data in violin plots? I have been trying to modify the below chunk of code with no luck. I have attempted grouping by SizeBin, coloring by SizeBin, etc. Any insight on code or alternatives is appreciated.

```
ggplot(data_frame, aes(x=Depth, 
             y=Biomass,
             fill=SizeBin)) + geom_violin()
```

| Depth | Biomass | SizeBin |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.5 | 6.86 | A |
| 2.5 | 3.51 | A |
| 2.5 | 2.45 | A |
| 1.5 | 0.80 | B |
| 2.5 | 1.34 | B |

Answer (score 1):

You can try to split the violin plot.
Here's how to do it: https://r-charts.com/distribution/split-violin-plot/

Or this: [Split violin plot with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717353/split-violin-plot-with-ggplot2)

I personally really like those plots.