# Violin plot in R, each column a violin, split by gender

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have a data structure where each row represents an individual, and each column represents something about that individual.

I want to plot multiple violins in a single violin plot, where each violin represents a column in my data matrix. But I want each column to be split into two groups, one for male and one for female. I need to be able to do it for ~10 columns.

For example, if we consider the following simple data matrix:

```
v1 v2 v3 v4 Sex
24 32 84 76 1
12 17 23 98 2
.. .. .. .. .
.. .. .. .. .
34 33 56 87 2
14 42 66 92 1
```

I want to plot v1, ..., v4 each as a violin split into two by sex. Something like illustrated below. How can I achieve this?[image]

Comment: I think this is more a coding question that belongs on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function `geom_split_violin` from the `introdataviz` package mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717353/split-violin-plot-with-ggplot2). First convert your data to longer format like this:

```r
df <- read.table(text = "v1 v2 v3 v4 Sex
24 32 84 76 1
12 17 23 98 2
34 33 56 87 2
14 42 66 92 1", header = TRUE)

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
# devtools::install_github("psyteachr/introdataviz")
library(introdataviz)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Sex) %>%
  mutate(Sex = factor(Sex)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value, fill = Sex)) +
  geom_split_violin()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>